# Do i have to register a DLL to use it in Excel?

Tags: excel, dll, vba

An older product we use has a 32-bit DLL that does Deflate compress/decompress. We import it in VBA thus:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function EtUnCompress Lib "CompPl32.dll" (ByVal SrcSt$, 
                                                          ByVal SrcLen As Long, 
                                                          Dest As Any, 
                                                          ByVal DestLen As Long) As Long
```

Some of our customers have 64-bit Office, so that's a problem. I was able to write my own 64-bit version using `System.IO.Compression`, with surprising ease.

*Now the question*

If I were to name my version CompPl32.dll and put it in System32, is that enough?

Or does my version *have* to be registered to work in Excel VBA?

I have 32-bit Office so I can't test this.

Comment: Did you have to register the 32 bit version to get it to work?

Comment: I don't know, it is installed by a 3rd party app. I'll look in the reg, but I'm not sure that will prove anything.

Comment: If it's installed by another app, odds are good it registers it.

Comment: I guess my real question is how does Lib "CompPl32.dll" work? Does it go to the registry, or does it look for that file?

Comment: Have you found the string `CompPl32.dll` in the Registry?